# Sequential Compactness Example, Not a Closed Interval

Tags: real-analysis

Is there an example of a subset of the real numbers that is sequentially compact but is not a closed interval or union of closed intervals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a complete metric space all variations of "compact" are equivalent, hence sequentially compact is equivalent to closed and bounded in $\mathbb{R}$.

So the answer is no, there is no such example.

Comment: Cool thanks, that's what I thought.

Comment: I think you need to assume it's a complete metric space.

Comment: So without that assumption this would be impossible to prove?

Comment: Closed and bounded doesn't imply compact if the metric space isn't complete. The set $S = \{x \in \mathbb{Q} : 0 \leq x \leq 1\} = [0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ is closed and bounded (as a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$) but is not compact: I can find a sequence in $S$ that doesn't can't have a convergent subsequence.  Take for instance a sequence of rationals converging to $\sqrt{2}/2$.

Comment: Quite right about "complete" being necessary.  Added that qualifier.